# Exporting from ArcGIS Pro results in clipped output

Tags: export, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to export a world map from ArcGIS Pro 2.2.4, using the > Share > Map Export option. The map is zoomed to the full extent of the world:

[image]

But the resulting PNG or PDF is clipped to a square extent which doesn't cover the whole visible extent, or the extent of the datasets:

[image]

This occurs whether or not I choose to export a world file. This is my first time really using ArcGIS Pro so I'm just following the steps I would have used in ArcMap. Are there any steps I'm missing?

If it makes any difference I'm running MacOS with Windows 10 inside a Parallels virtual machine.

Comment: I added the same layers to ArcMap, and it exported as expected at the full extent....

Comment: I think I've noticed this. I'd try putting it into a map frame that fills a layout and export from that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response from an Esri developer is that this is a bug (he didn't use that word) which is fixed in version 2.3 of ArcGIS Pro.

The workaround for now is to add a Layout and export from that.

Comment: My colleague is facing same issue with 2.4.3